# Simple Help Desk app that integrates with TFS

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

i'm looking for an app for our small office that would be used as help desk for submitting tickets/computer related issues etc. Nothing to complex. Since we're also using TFS for bug tracking i would like to integrate it with TFS.

Comment: I've voted to close this as it's not programming related but also wanted to add a comment querying why you'd want to integrate with TFS? Unless of course you produce software that's used internally and want to be able to track bugs raised from help desk -> TFS? If not, beware of trying to make one tool (TFS) do lots of different jobs, it seldom ends well.

Comment: Unless of course you produce software that's used internally and want to be able to track bugs raised from help desk -> TFS - YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Kayako - http://www.kayako.com

They are writing a REST Api that you should be able to integrate TFS with

http://forums.kayako.com/threads/microsoft-tfs-2010-integration.23893/

Comment: BUT note that Kayako doesn't have any ready to use TFS nor VSO integration plugin. All you need to write on your own. So why not use some good free opensource solution for that which supports REST API ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at TFSDesk

http://www.tfsdesk.com

It is focused on the integration between the service desk tickets and TFS workitems, and it works with Visual Studio Online or with your on-premises TFS.

Comment: your on-premises TFS must be accessible to Internet :)